# How to convert a filtered time-domain signal into frequency one?

Tags: fft, filters, bandpass

I have a signal in matlab like this:

[image: Signal]

I have designed a band-pass filter in 16-32 MHz range:

[image]

and applied the filter to the signal,

[image]

the result is like this :

[image]

**My Question:**

**what is the easiest way to convert this time-domain signal into a frequency based signal?**

can I export the signal into workspace and use the data variable?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get the Fourier transform of the signal?

Comment: @Phonon....Yes!

Comment: This is a question about programming, not signal processing, and should be migrated to stackoverflow.com.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the FFT will give you a frequency representation of the data:

y=fft(sig3.data);

Comment: Thank you...actually I want to be sure that using the "data" variable is the right thing!